# How to implement web camera and mobile camera on Meteor

Tags: javascript, mobile, meteor, camera

I need to implement a photo capture on Meteor. Is there any Meteor package to achieve image capturing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm using the **mdg:camera** package. It's simple and useful.

```
meteor add mdg:camera
```

First you can create a link on the html side.

```
<template name="example">
    <a href="#" class="takePhoto">take photo</a>
    <img class="photo">
</template>
```

After clicking, you can change the captured picture.

```
Template.example.events({
    'click .takePhoto': function(e, instance) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var cameraOptions = {
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        };

        MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
           if (error) {
               return; // here maybe you can give an error.
           }

           instance.$('.photo').attr('src', data);
        });
    }
});
```

You can also check here for some picture options:

https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:camera/README.md#meteorcameragetpictureoptions-callback

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.